# Hibernate - Tomcat - MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, struts, c3p0

**Dear All,**
I'm testing a *Struts webApp using hibernate-mysql on tomcat7...*

After the 8 hours timeout period my webApp always **crashes**. I've changed configurations here and there. But no success.

I really appreciate your attention...

Here some lines from *hibernate.xml*

---

```
 property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">600
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true
    property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true
    property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stockdb?autoReconnect=true
```

---

Here are some of lines from my stacktraces:

---

```
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
    WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
    ...



WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
...

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.



...
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
...



at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.getMaxRows(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1200)




at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:212)


...
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
...
```

Please help!

Comment: Tomcat has [a built-in database connection pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html), rendering c3p0 unnecessary.

Comment: awesome. that's totally new for my poor knowledge.... Thank you so much for the hint.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer, along with some configuration details from the page, so you can accept it in a second

Comment: please... that's very nice of you...

Comment: Sorted, good luck and let me know if you have further problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) has [a database connection pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html) that's included out of the box. To configure [MySQL](http://mysql.com), for example:

```
<Context>

    <!-- maxActive: Maximum number of database connections in pool. Make sure you
         configure your mysqld max_connections large enough to handle
         all of your db connections. Set to -1 for no limit.
         -->

    <!-- maxIdle: Maximum number of idle database connections to retain in pool.
         Set to -1 for no limit.  See also the DBCP documentation on this
         and the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis configuration parameter.
         -->

    <!-- maxWait: Maximum time to wait for a database connection to become available
         in ms, in this example 10 seconds. An Exception is thrown if
         this timeout is exceeded.  Set to -1 to wait indefinitely.
         -->

    <!-- username and password: MySQL username and password for database connections  -->

    <!-- driverClassName: Class name for the old mm.mysql JDBC driver is
         org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - we recommend using Connector/J though.
         Class name for the official MySQL Connector/J driver is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
         -->

    <!-- url: The JDBC connection url for connecting to your MySQL database.
         -->

  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

Then you'll need to configure your connection as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUsername("root");
        p.setPassword("password");
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(10);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
 p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setPoolProperties(p); 

        Connection con = null;
        con = datasource.getConnection();
```

Now, proceed as one normally would with your JDBC code.

Comment: please tell me this...
how can I combine with hibernate and struts... would it be a conflict?

Comment: Given that [one of the most respected Java bloggers](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-hibernate-integration-example/) has a tutorial on just that, I'm guessing it would not be a conflict.

Comment: Sure I'll vote you up... But my reputation is not enough for that yet. But I will vote definitely.

Comment: Hello again... 
I'm using tomcat connection pool. So far it works fine. But sometimes it gives 
SQLException "PooledConnection has already been closed."
Have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Play with the maxActive, maxAllowed, and maxWait parameters in the XML, along with the times specified in the Java code. Hope that helps. If you're still having trouble, edit your question with your code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: no luck my friend... sadly still the same error as when i've been using the c3p0 pooling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424174/issue-with-tomcat-pooling-with-hibernate-mysql-timeout

Comment: Don't use c3p0 with tomcat, it has built-in database pooling.