# Issue with Tomcat pooling with Hibernate. MySQL timeout

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, struts

I've been developing a **struts web app with hibernate3 on tomcat7 using MySQL**. At first i've been using c3p0 pooling... then I've swithched to **tomcat pooling**. But I get the same error after a one day. Every morning we have to restart the server.

The log shows `java.lang.NullPointerException` like this

```
sm.Login.execute(Login.java:24)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452) 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
interceptors.SessionCheck.intercept(SessionCheck.java:47)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:43)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

---

my META-INF/context.xml is here,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/sealmanagement">
```

```
        RemoveAbandoned="true" 

        maxAllowed="150" 
        maxIdle="15" 

        name="jdbc/stockdb" 

        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 

    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stockdb?autoReconnect=true"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username="root"
    password="1234"
    jmxEnabled="true"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    testOnReturn="true"
    validationInterval="3000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    maxActive="100"
    initialSize="10"
    maxWait="1000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
    minIdle="10"
    logAbandoned="true"
```

jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"

```
        />
```

---

and hibernate.cfg.xml is following,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>


   <!-- using container-managed JNDI -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">
java:comp/env/jdbc/stockdb
</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>       


<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
```

---

```
 package dbcon;


import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory object.
 *
 * 
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

---

event though it doesn't affect I've put PoolProperties class in java code as well. May be it could be the isse...

here is the Getdbcon.java

```
package dbcon;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

public class Getdbcon {
    //get mysql connection // -- shehan
    public Connection getmysqlConnection() throws SQLException {

        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stockdb?auto_reconnect=true");
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUsername("root");
        p.setPassword("1234");
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT * from userlogin where 1 limit 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(true);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(2);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(false);

 p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setPoolProperties(p); 

        Connection con = null;
        try{
        con = datasource.getConnection();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return con;



    }
```

---

and here some lines from tomcat startup log console... think they are useful

```
INFO: JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
Mar 15, 2013 9:00:08 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 15, 2013 9:00:08 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 15, 2013 9:00:08 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
Mar 15, 2013 9:00:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
Mar 15, 2013 9:00:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
```

---

Please put your kind attention on this. You are very well appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've added HibernateUtil.java and Getdbcon.java files. Please take a look....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I've added ***wait_timeout*** variable at the end of the ***my.ini***.
and given the maximum value to it.
[according to this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Then everything solved. Not that issue is bothering me anymore.

thank you [hd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783412/hd1) for help.

Answer (score 1):

`autoReconnect=true` is not recommended, [justification lies here](http://mysqlpreacher.com/wordpress/2010/06/mysql-jdbc-connector-autoreconnecttrue/).

Generally, you shouldn't be making JDBC connections yourself from within hibernate. The [Hibernate Session object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) has a createQuery and createSQLQuery method that makes most JDBC code superfluous. I say *most* because I haven't figured out a way to do a [VACUUM ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-vacuum.html) from within Hibernate, so I have to make a separate JDBC connection to do so, but barring edge cases like that, you really shouldn't mix JDBC and Hibernate.

Comment: No... you shouldn't *write* JDBC code when using Hibernate. Hibernate is built on JDBC, after all.

Comment: yeah i understood. So how should I initiate the connection? Can I do it without Getdbcon.java?

Comment: Join [Dnews on freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/) and I'll help you there. It seems you can't chat here unless you have 20 reputation.

Comment: thanks hd1... you did a big help... Thanks... I'll go further as your suggestions.. see ya

Comment: finally I've removed all the pooling systems and checked only with hibernate3. But the issue is the same. The stacktrace suggests to add autoReconnect=true option. I've tried it too. No success.